# Select distinct elements in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, distinct

I have following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
   <result>
      <status>A</status>
   </result>
   <result>
      <status>A</status>
   </result>
   <result>
      <status>B</status>
   </result>
</results>
```

And I want to get the result elements based on the distinct value of child element status . i.e in above case only one result element should be return which contains A

```
   <result>
      <status>A</status>
   </result>
   <result>
      <status>B</status>
   </result>
```

Appreciate your help on this to get a working xpath expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath-2.0 you can use the [`distinct-values(...)`](https://www.w3.org/2005/04/xpath-functions/#distinct-values) function with a for-loop like this:

```
for $d in distinct-values(/results/result/status) return /results/result[status=$d][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one to get required output:

```
/results/result[not(status=preceding-sibling::result/status)]
```

It should return `result` node in case there were no preceding `result` node with the same `status` value (distinct `result` nodes)